# XPath and PHP troubleshooting

Tags: php, xpath

I get this error:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
```

Applies to: 
**echo $result->Data;**

And this output:

```
Array ()
```

**Background Informations**

A function returns a string which contains an XML file.

I want to get some data from two tags and deal with them on their own.

**String Data**

```
$data="
<SyncML xmlns='SYNCML:SYNCML1.0'> 
<SyncHdr> 
</SyncHdr> 
<SyncBody> 
   <betameta>
         WANT 1
   </betameta> 
   <Add> 
      <Data>
         WANT 2
      </Data>
   </Add> 
</SyncBody> 
</SyncML>";
```

In the above data, I want values "WANT 1" and "WANT 2"

**Code so far**

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
$result = $xml->xpath("/SyncML/SyncBody");
print_r($result);
echo $result->Data;
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only solution I can find is the following:

```
<?php

$data= <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SyncML> 
<SyncHdr> 
</SyncHdr> 
<SyncBody> 
   <betameta>
         WANT 1
   </betameta> 
   <Add> 
      <Data>
         WANT 2
      </Data>
   </Add> 
</SyncBody> 
</SyncML>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
$result = $xml->xpath("/SyncML/SyncBody");
print_r($result);
echo $result;
```

is there anyway you can loose the xmlns?

This will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [betameta] => 
         WANT 1

            [Add] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [Data] => 
         WANT 2

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Fantastic!  I'll chop the xmlns out!

Thank you, Martin!

Comment: @Sochin: I would not recommend this. Deal with the namespace, it's easy enough (see Rik's answer).

Answer (score 2):

```
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('default','SYNCML:SYNCML1.0');
$result = $xml->xpath("/default:SyncML/default:SyncBody");
```

Comment: +1, much better than kicking out the namespace from the source.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the trailing slash.

Comment: Thanks, did that and now I get "Array ( ) "

Comment: Yes, access item 0 in your array to get your only result.

Comment: I'm using: print_r($result);

Doesn't that output all entries in the array?

Comment: Maybe you need to specify the namespace which you declared in the xmlns attribute?